# "two thirds" or "two third (of members)"

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement

> **Two thirds** of the **members** are needed to pass the **resolutions** for the impeachment of the president.

The verb *are needed* is according to the plural noun *members*.

But why did we use ***two thirds*** here?
Can't we use ***two third*** because we generally say, *"Two third of the students are absent"*?

Comment: "two third of the students are absent" is incorrect for the same reason that "two third of the members..." is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing out fractions, the numerator determines whether the denominator must be plural or not.

If the numerator is 1, then the denominator is singular.

If the numerator is anything else, including zero, the denominator must be plural.

So:

- 1/3 = one-third
- 5/8 = five-eighths
- 0/4 = zero-fourths
- -1/10 = negative one-tenth
- -5/9 = negative five-ninths

Therefore:

- 2/3 = two thirds

So, in your example, it is only correct to say or write out "two-thirds" because 2 is something other than one.

Here's some information on the vocabulary of fractions from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29) article (emphasis added):

> When reading fractions it is customary in English to pronounce the denominator using the corresponding ordinal number, **in plural if the numerator is not one**, as in "fifths" for fractions with a 5 in the denominator. Thus, 3/5 is rendered as three fifths and 5/32 as five thirty-seconds. This generally applies to whole number denominators greater than 2, though large denominators that are not powers of ten are often rendered using the cardinal number. Thus, 5/123 might be rendered as "five one-hundred-twenty-thirds", but is often "five over one hundred twenty-three". In contrast, because one million is a power of ten, 6/1,000,000 is usually expressed as "six millionths" or "six one-millionths", rather than as "six over one million".

Comment: Oh wow. Is this the rule? I wasn't aware of this rule. Thanks for this. But I don't know but my teacher said that the sentence two third of the students are absent is correct.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this rule. Thanks much  . But my teacher said that the sentence two third of students are absent is correct.

Comment: @SeemaBhukar Well... based on the English conventions (at least in the US), your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Note that either positive or negative one takes the singular. Negative one tenth, but negative three tenths.

Answer (score 1):

The denomination of something is its kind or type.

Money, for example, comes in different denomination: one-dollar bills, five-dollar bills, twenty-dollar bills, etc. If we have one five-dollar bill, we use the singular. If we have 3 five dollar bills, we use the plural—even though in each case, we have more than a single dollar.

The denominator of a fractions expresses the number of equal parts that a whole is broken into. “The denominator is ‘de name’ of the fraction.” The numerator states how many of these parts we have. So one third is singular, we only have one of these pieces. Two thirds is plural, we have two of the pieces.

Returning to the example of money, consider quarters. A quarter is a coin worth 25¢ or 1/4 of a dollar. How many quarters do we have? One quarter, two quarters, three quarters: singular for one of them, plural for more than one. This is despite the fact that if we were denominating our money in cents or dollars, each is multiple cents but less than a single dollar.

“Two third of the students are absent” would always be incorrect, on two counts. The unit is thirds, and there are two of them, so we need the plural, and also, written fractions are always hyphenated, regardless of the part of speech they represent. Therefore, we say “Two-thirds of the students are absent.”