# Two thirds versus two third

Tags: usage

In the following sentence

> [They constitute the requisite ***two-thirds*** of the 18-member Congress Legislature Party.](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/unconscionable-switch/article27690242.ece)

**two thirds** is used but can I use **two third** in the same sentence

They constitute the requisite **two third** of the.............

Comment: You can have a ***second*** *third*, but *two* indicates a plural, so it needs to be followed by a plural. *One apple* or *two apples*. *One third* or *two thirds*.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69207/two-thirds-or-two-third-of-members/270219#270219

Answer (score 1):

> can I use two third in the same sentence[?]

No. In a fraction where the numerator is greater than one, the denominator is plural. One third, two thirds.